# how to represent distance information from 3d camera with RGB

Tags: 3d, kinect, point-cloud-library

I have got a distance matrix from a 3D-sensor, how can I represent the distance information with different colors(RGB). For example, red means short range, green means medium range and blue means long range.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the points into a PointXYZRGB cloud, but set the r,g,b values depending on your range value. So something like:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr pointCloudXYZItoXYZRGB(const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr in)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr out(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    // Fill in the cloud data
    out->width = in->width;
    out->height = in->height;
    out->is_dense = false;
    out->points.resize(in->width * in->height);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < in->points.size(); ++i)
    {
        out->points[i].x = in->at(i).x;
        out->points[i].y = in->at(i).y;
        out->points[i].z = in->at(i).z;

        if (out->points[i].y > 5)
        {
             out->points[i].r = 255;
             out->points[i].g = 0;
             out->points[i].b = 0;
        } //etc
    }

    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB use colour maps. Assuming your depth data are stored in a 16-bits single channel image, use the code below.

```
im=imread(‘pathtoyourimage’)
clrd=ind2rgb(im, jet(2^13))
```